# Splitting a line into multi-line at desired points in arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, splitting, advanced-license-level

I am currently working on a project in ArcGIS 10.1 Advanced license regarding the a single facility multiple destination analysis. But, I encountered a problem. I have to separate line features into multiple segments at desired points. And also I wanted each segment identified individually after the separation of lines at points. I have to do this for network analysi[image]s.

The lines and points are shapefiles. The points are generated at using fixed distance tool. To evaluate time for each segment between the points, I need distance between those points. So, please suggest me any method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to ArcGIS, you can use the Split Line at Point tool.

Using the arcpy library the following command should work

arcpy.SplitLineAtPoint_management("streets.shp","points.shp","splitline_out.shp","20 Meters")

That will split street features where they intersect the points layer, or are within 20 meters of them.  You can play with the search radius to find what works best for you.

[link to documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000)